# curl to elasticsearch container in Docker tutorial returns an "unlisted" container?

Tags: docker

This official beginner's tutorial at [tutorial link](https://docker-curriculum.com/) is humbling...please see below:

[image: from https://docker-curriculum.com/]

It is supposed to give the above output with `cluster_name` `elasticsearch` but I get the following:

```
root@14413fdd3ada:/opt/flask-app# curl 172.17.0.2:9200                                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                                     
  "name" : "JNOKOND",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "tr4BVq4zT4WlGPRxSxp9EA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.3.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "053779d",
    "build_date" : "2018-07-20T05:20:23.451332Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.3.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
```

So something called `docker-cluster` instead of `elasticsearch`

Does anyone know why this is so?

Comment: Where is the tutorial ?

Comment: @BlueClouds sorry, I just added it

Comment: That configuration is in - /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml [docker exec -it <containerid_ElasticSearch> sh]. You may override that value by passing environment variable "cluster.name" in docker-compose.yml under es service.

Comment: @SujayPillai sounds good, I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

This is totally my bad (newbie here).  I think Sujay above mentions something about config but I got it working by stopping all containers and then running the following four commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

# build the flask container
docker build -t prakhar1989/foodtrucks-web .

# create the network
docker network create foodtrucks-net

# start the ES container
docker run -d --name es --net foodtrucks-net -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2

# start the flask app container
docker run -d --net foodtrucks-net -p 5000:5000 --name foodtrucks-web prakhar1989/foodtrucks-web
```

Where as before I think (sorry but my newbie memory is not that good) I did the first three commands and then ran the fourth one in detached mode (ie. not in the `foodtrucks-web` network) so the flask app container was running the default bridge network.

Comment: What did you do differently than before?

Comment: @BlueClouds I'm pretty sure that is where I screwed up.

Comment: @BlueClouds I edited the answer to explain what I did.